# Utils package does not have modules

Tags: python, module

I an trying to implement parts of the code I found here:https://github.com/Esri/raster-functions/blob/master/functions/SelectByPixelSize.py#L68-L73 . It's on raster and image processing in the ArcGIS environment.

In the example script, I need to use the 'Trace' method from the 'utils' package. I installed the package with `pip install utils`. But when I go to use the package, I can't load anything.

Ex:

```
import utils
utils.Trace()
```

I get the error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Trace'`

I actually can't find any module to load from 'utils' package. The `__init__.py` file is empty.
I am using Python 2.7.10.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code comes with a `utils.py` You don't need to install anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to use his [file](https://github.com/Esri/raster-functions/blob/master/functions/utils.py#L86).

Download it to the same folder of your code and run it again!